# Prevent whitespace in a string after one is entered

Tags: android, string, substring, whitespace

I made a code where user can't enter first space in a string.
User is allowed to enter white space after min 2 characters.
I need to redefine my method so user enters white space once, and only once after the two or more characters. After that it should be prevented. How do I do that?

```js
case UPDATE_NAME:
     if (firstName.getText().toString().startsWith(" "))
  firstName.setText(firstName.getText().toString().trim());

     if (firstName.getText().toString().contains("  "))
  firstName.setText(firstName.getText().toString().replace("  ", " "));

     int indexOfSpace = firstName.getText().toString().lastIndexOf(" ");
     if (indexOfSpace > 0) {
  String beforeSpace = firstName.getText().toString().substring(0, indexOfSpace);
  String[] splitted = beforeSpace.split(" ");
  if (splitted != null && splitted.length > 0) {
      if (splitted[splitted.length - 1].length() < 2)
   firstName.setText(firstName.getText().toString().trim());
  }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). I [made one](http://regexr.com/3empb) that should match your requirements.

```
\S{2}\S*\s\S*\n

Explanation:
\S{2} two non whitespace
\S* n non whitespace
\s a whitespace
\S* n non whitespace
\n newline (i only added that for regexr, you may not need it)
```

Alternate way:
Iterate over `String.charAt(int)`, return false if there is a whitespace in the first two chars, count all whitespaces, return false if n > 1.

Comment: how do I add the alphabet into this pattern

Comment: \S is defacto the alphabet/digits/etc. It contains everything character with the exception of the whitespace,

Answer (score 1):

This method should meet your requirements:

```
private static boolean isValidFirstName(String firstName) {
    if (firstName != null && !firstName.startsWith(" ")) {
        int numberOfSpaces = firstName.length() - firstName.replace(" ", "").length();
        if (firstName.length() < 2 || numberOfSpaces <= 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use a TextWatcher

```
public class CustomWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private String myText;
private int count = 0;

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
    myText= s;
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    //check if there is a space in the first 2 characters, if so, sets the string to the previous before the space
    if(s.length() < 3 && s.contains(" "))
        s= myText;

    //if the length is higher than 2, and the count is higher than 0 (1 space added already), puts the string back if a space is entered
    else if(s.contains(" ") && count > 0)
        s= myText;

    //If none of the above is verified and you enter a space, increase count so the previous if statement can do its job
    else if(s.contains(" "))
        count++;

}
```

}

And then, set it to your EditText

```
mTargetEditText.addTextChangedListener(new CustomWatcher());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control your editText(I assume) with a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), you would only need to check inside afterTextChanged() if length is <2 and else if the string contains the char " ".